# Start the second command when seeing certain keyword appeared in console

Tags: bash

I am running two python programs, say `a.py, b.py`

What I want to run two programs by `python3 a.py` and `python3 b.py`, but `python3 b.py` needs to be run only when `python3 a.py` prompt a line with only"hello" on the screen - `a.py` will keep running.

Is it possible to achieve this on the Ubuntu terminal?

Answer (score 1):

You could send `a.py`'s output to a file and watch that file:

```
python3 a.py > output.log &
tail -n+1 -f output.log | grep -q hello && python3 b.py
```

The first command runs `a.py` in the background, while sending the output to `output.log`. The second command then sends the contents of `output.log` to `grep`, which checks for `hello`. If `grep` exits successfully, indicating `hello` was found, `b.py` is run.

Note that the timing is not exact. Due to buffering, the second script will be started some time after `hello` shows up in the output.

Comment: so if I put a bracket is it like `(python3 a.py > output.log &
tail -n+1 -f output.log | (grep -q hello && python3 b.py))`

Comment: @william007 do you want the first script's output to be the input of the second script?

Comment: not really,  the output is used to decide whether to start the second script

Comment: Then `(python3 a.py > output.log & (tail -n+1 -f output.log | grep -q hello) && python3 b.py)` is closer to what I put in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, is it 
`(python3 a.py > output.log & ((tail -n+1 -f output.log | grep -q hello) && python3 b.py))`?

Comment: That looks OK, but why do you need so many brackets?